# Is it possible to divide a function into two parts using struct?

Tags: c, struct

As the title says, I tried this following example :

```
struct tparams {
    double y;
    double* dxda;
};

typedef struct tparams Struct;

Struct cof( ) {
    Struct s;
    double y;
    double* dxda= (double*)malloc(12 * sizeof(*dxda));
    
    double a = 50;
    double b = 78;

    y= pow((a * b) / 4, 2);
    
    *dxda = (a / 8) * pow(b, 2);

    s.dxda = dxda;
    s.y = y;
    return s;
}   

void func() {
    Struct result;
    double y;

    result = cof();
    y = result.y;
    printf("result1: %g \n", y);
}

void deriv() {
    Struct result;
    double* dxda = (double*)malloc(12 * sizeof(*dxda));

    result = cof();
    dxda = result.dxda;
    printf("result2: %g \n", *dxda);        
}

int main()
{
    func();
    deriv();
}
```

I have a more difficult example that I am working on and was trying to make it as close as possible. Can I, in this case use the Struct result only once to divide the function and its Derivative into two functions?

If I call Struct result twice in func() and deriv(), it calculates the function cof() twice which makes it take longer. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Start by giving the functions meaningful names then take it from there. In either case, You'll want to avoid the situation where you end up with a partially initialized struct.

Comment: Also `double* dxda = (double*)malloc(12 * sizeof(*dxda));` followed by `dxda = result.dxda;` doesn't make any sense, as latter just overwrites `dxda`.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? It really looks overly complicated and I have the impression your overall approach is wrong.

Comment: Why are you allocating an array of 12 doubles when you only use one at all? From what the code reveals it doesn't appear meaningful at all to use dynamically allocated memory you just risk running into memory leaks – well, you actually *do* run into!

Comment: All your function actually produces are two values. Why don't you just return these in the struct directly? `struct tparams { double y; double dxda; };` (note: no pointer!). Your function doesn't rely on dynamically allocated memory, then it should not allocate either. You don't really need intermediate variables either, you can assign to the struct members directly: `Struct s; s.y = a*b/4; s.y = s.y*s.y; s.dxda = a/8*b*b; return s;` Don't make your life more complicated than necessary...

Comment: @Aconcagua I actually remembered your advice to change the pow() but forgot to add it. I'm sorry Abt that

Comment: You repeatedly call `func` with all the same values – you can avoid (you asked a similar question anyway) if you calculate it once within `main` (!), store the result there and pass it to the functions as parameter. And I'd have `a` and `b` as parameters again as you had in your former question. All in all this might look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/feWq1a3EG).

Comment: Never mind about `pow` – can happen ;)

Comment: And note that `Struct` is a really unlucky name for a data type – *anything* aggregating a bunch of variables is a struct, so that's not descriptive at all...

Comment: who is freeing the memory allocated in `cof()`? In `derif()` why allocate memory (not freed) and then just reassign the pointer to the pointer of the struct? Why can't you print `*result.dxda` or `result.y`? Why do you not call `cof()` and pass the result struct as arguments to the functions `func()` and `deriv()`? Why don't you just print the 2 struct values in `main()` after calling `cof()`

Comment: `sizeof(*dxda)` does this compile? Why don't you write a function that allocates 12 (or n) doubles and use it multiple times?

Comment: @rioV8 "sizeof(*dxda) does this compile? " --> `sizeof(*dxda)` is fine and preferable to `sizeof(double)`.  When you tried compiling it, did it have trouble?

Answer (score 1):

> If I call Struct result twice in func() and deriv(), it calculates the function cof() twice which makes it take longer. I would like to avoid that.

Code needs to share the value stored in `result` between the 2 functions: `func()` and `deriv()`.

A simple approach is to pass a pointer the structure to the 2 functions so they share that data.

```
void func(Struct *result_ptr) {
    //Struct result;

    // result = cof();
    *result_ptr = cof(); // Save the result in location provided.
    ...

}

void deriv(Struct *result_ptr) {
    // Struct result;
    // result = cof();
    // dxda = result.dxda;
    dxda = result_ptr->dxda;  // Use the result passed in.
    ...
}

int main() {
    //func();
    //deriv();
    Struct result = { 0 };
    func(&result);
    deriv(&result);
}
```

---

Tip: weak object naming and missing `free()` obfuscates the key issue.   OP needs to improve that too.